# Find the greatest leg of right triangle having a median only

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

The median drawn to the hypotenuse is equal to $2\sqrt3$. Find the greatest leg.

Comment: Make a picture of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your point moves on a semi-circle radius $ r=2 \sqrt 3$  and diameter  $d=4 \sqrt 3$ with side   $ a = d \cos\,\theta$.

This $a$ is larger of two sides if $ \pi/4> \theta > 0 $ else it is the other side.

Answer (score 1):

The longer leg limit is $4 \sqrt 3$ as the point B moves toward C
[image]